# how to make line plots with foreground and background?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2

How in the world do you make line plots with multiple lines in one plot, but where each line is set into the background, almost as if it is 3D?

See example pictures below: [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R you can get pretty close like this:

```r
library(ggridges)

set.seed(69)

df <- data.frame(x = as.vector(sapply(14:10, function(i) rnorm(30, i, 2))),
                 group = rep(letters[1:5], each = 30))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y = group, fill = group)) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 10), size = 2, color = "#5078be") +
  geom_density_ridges(size = 2, aes(color = group)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 3), size = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#8f4b4a", "#c08f33", "#e2baba", "#ffe2ae", "#83a8f1")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#5c1a08", "#8c5b01", "#af8987", "#d2ab83", "#5078be")) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do that kind of plot (a ridgeline plot) in `R` check out the `ggridges` package.  This will show you a pile of cool examples:

```
browseVignettes("ggridges")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a z-axis. You can still adjust the design and hide the axes and so on as you like.

```
from scipy import exp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

def gaus(x, a, x0, sigma):
    return a*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.array([i for i in range(0, 100)])
    y1 = gaus(x, 1, 50, 5)
    y2 = gaus(x, 1, 45, 12)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    ax.view_init(-90, 90)

    ax.plot3D(x, y1, 100)
    ax.plot3D(x, y2, 1)
    plt.show()
```